# using WPF Button (boolean and changing color )

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new here, so help me please

I'm going try to explain my issue, so I'm using WPF, I'm making sort of Calculator, now I have button called "log".

so what I need, is as long as I do not click (activate) the button, nothing should be overwritten to a text document, but if I click on it, the color of the button must change ( like gray ) and it must be set on true, from that moment every operation I make with the calculator has to be overwritten to a text file.

Somebody can help me please

the code of the button Log:

```
<Button Content="Log" Name="btnLog" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
         Background="#1d1c1c" Foreground="Aqua" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" 
         Margin="4,89,0,0" Height="27" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15" 
         Click="btnLog_Click"/>
```

Comment: Have you made any attempts at a solution yet? We cannot write your code entirely from scratch (xaml code for a button doesn't really count since you haven't tried to code any of your own logic into it). If you have some written code trying to solve it, please add to your question.

Comment: i haven't tried anything yet because i dont know how to begin with this button, my calculator is almost done, i just need to overwrite all my operations now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to look into `ToggleButton`, which already does what you want.

Here's an example on how to style it to your need, also use the `Checked` event instead of the `Click` event for that control.

```
    <ToggleButton Content="Log" 
                  Name="btnLog" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                  Foreground="Aqua" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  Width="75" 
                  Margin="4,89,0,0" 
                  Height="27" 
                  FontWeight="Bold" 
                  FontSize="15" 
                  Checked="btnLog_Checked">
        <ToggleButton.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1d1c1c"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ToggleButton.Style>
    </ToggleButton>
```

Comment: thanks a lot i'm gonna try this

Comment: Roger Leblanc its working perfectly

thanks a lot Man!!!!